# how to enable custom fields in the Gutenberg post editor

Tags: custom-field, block-editor

Apparently ([from this website](https://www.buildthatwebsite.com/custom-fields-gutenberg));

> To view your custom fields using native WP functionality, click the
> settings button (three dots) and then go to options, where you can
> enable the Custom Fields box.

This is what I see:

[image]

How do I enable custom fields in the Gutenberg editor the way they used to be present in the classic editor?

Help appreciated.

Comment: have you asked this on the support forums? Custom fields show for me under the Additional section, but keep in mind this is a programmers stack not a user support stack, so unless a code based solution can be found there may be no answer to this question that fits the scope of the stack. It's also possible one of the plugins you added removed it, or the role you used to test this cannot have custom fields. Also where is that quote from?

Comment: Yeah, I did ask the question in the Gutenberg plugin support forum on wordpress.org. Haven't received a response. None of our plugins affects the post editor. I have administrator privileges. @TomJNowell

Comment: the only clue in the gutenberg code is that wether that is shown or not is coming from PHP code in WordPress core based around the `enable_custom_fields` user meta value. The only conclusion I can draw is that custom fields don't show because you told it not to show via a UI setting or code elsewhere. Either that or it's something really silly like not realising you can scroll down or an old version of WordPress.

Comment: @TomJNowell, there is nothing about `enable_custom_fields` in the child theme `functions.php`. The Code Snippets plugin is installed, but no snippet is referencing posts or `enable_custom_fields`. I am scrolling all the way down in Gutenberg preferences, and we have `WP 5.9.3` installed.

Comment: other plugins have other methods to remove that panel via JS, you would need to disable them to verify this isn't happening, until you actually test via a process of elimination by deactivating plugins and switching to the default theme then you won't find the cause. Otherwise this is a development stack, unless the solution to your answer is code you may not find the type of answer you expected. Otherwise the _canonical_ answer would be that you go into the settings and check the toggle

Answer (score 1):

If using Advanced Custom Fields / "ACF" , this field is disabled by default after v5.6.0 .

---

This worked in a theme functions.php:

`add_filter( 'acf/settings/remove_wp_meta_box', '__return_false' );`

Then enable custom fields by,

Classic -> Screen Options -> Custom Fields checkbox

or

Block Editor -> Three Dots -> Panels -> Additional -> Custom fields toggle

---

ACF docs at https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-settings/

Discussion at

- https://github.com/AdvancedCustomFields/acf/issues/65
- https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-enable-custom-fields-in-the-gutenberg-editor/
- https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf-pro-5-6-0-unable-to-display-regular-custom-fields-metabox-on-cpts/